# Multiple CGAffineTransforms in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, core-animation

In Swift 2, we could do this to get a rotation and a stretch:

```
let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1) 
let stretchAndRotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.8, 0.8) 
label.transform = stretchAndRotate
```

In Swift 3, CGAffineTransformScale has become CGAffineTransform and no longer accepts a rotation.

What is the simplest way to apply a stretch and rotation to an object now?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Note that Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax... does the conversion automatically for you ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Swift 3 many global C functions are mapped to *member functions*
of the corresponding type, compare
["Import as member"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md) on swift-evolution.

In your case it would be

```
let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 1.0)
let stretchAndRotate = rotate.scaleBy(x: 0.8, y: 0.8)
```